# Variable 'TargetProcess' hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: vb.net

So im making a dll injector and im getting this error: Variable 'TargetProcess' hides a variable in an enclosing block.

Code:

```
Dim httpclient = New Net.WebClient
httpclient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ftp_username", "ftp_password")
httpclient.DownloadFile("ftp:/you.gifrsite.com/Cheat.dll", Application.StartupPath & "\Cheat.dll")
IO.File.Move(Application.StartupPath & "\Cheat.dll", Cheat)
Dim TargetProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCESS NAME")
If TargetProcess.Length = 0 Then Me.TextBox1.Text = ("Waiting for GAME.exe")
```

Comment: I don't want to support cheats or hacks ;)

Comment: im actually making hacks for my own game :P

Comment: You have another variable with the name `TargetProcess`. Rename one of both. Since the one we see is an array i'd name it `targetProcesses`

Comment: The compiler is telling the truth. You have two variables with the same name inside your current scope (e.g. method)

Comment: i cant rename one tho because then i get errors

Comment: Ohh worked thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [compiler error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk40des.aspx) is meaningful, you have two variables with the same name inside this scope. Rename one of both. Since `Process.GetProcessesByName` returns an `Process()`(so possibly multiple) i'd name it `targetProcesses`(plural):

```
Dim targetProcesses As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCESS NAME")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Need to wait 4 minutes :P